# I accidentally sent 10 Ethereum to my Ethereum Classic wallet in Bittrex

Tags: wallets

I accidentally sent 10 Ethereum to my Ethereum Classic wallet in Bittrex. Please help i’m despirate. I’m very new to this crypto currency and this is a hard earned money.

Bittrex replied they only recover if the value is more than $5,000 for a fee of 0.1 Bitcoin. Mine has a value of only $2,500.

Is there a way to recover this?

Thank you do much.

Answer (score 0):

The basic is that there is no `ETH` address or `ETHC` address separately. Just like Bitcoin and bitcoin cash.

If the Exchange has private keys of the address which they have sure then they can recover it.

> Ethereum is nothing but Fork of Ethereum Classic so the address will
>   be same only.

It is just monopoly of Exchanges these days that they don't recover funds and says that you send to specific address only.

There is no way you can manage to convince them until you go to Twitter and reddit and keep on making thread to get attention.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, throwing a tantrum on Reddit or Twitter slows down the entire support process....for everyone. Bittrex has a stellar reputation when it comes to dealing with customers in this exact situation. Open a ticket, wait, be nice, say please and thank you, provide all necessary information.